# OpenCV: How can I calculate the area of a white region?

Tags: python, opencv, area

I have a black image with a big white spot on it and I want to calculate the area of this white spot. Which is the best way to calculate this ? I'm using OpenCV in Python.

Answer (score 2):

To find the Area follow these steps:

1. Apply thresholding & Binarize the  input image.
2. Find Contours.
3. Find the Area of Contours by using cv.ContourArea();

[refer this example](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html#table-of-content-contours) for further reference.